# Reading txt file, then count unique words and put them into arraylist

Tags: java

I got this assignment for school and all my other methods are working just fine, but reading unique words just doesn't work for me.

My method for reading txtfile:

```
public void lesBok(String filnavn) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(filnavn);
    Scanner innlestfil = new Scanner(file);
    while (innlestfil.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = innlestfil.nextLine();
        if((ord.contains(s))){
              for(i = 0; i < ord.size(); i++){
                if(ord.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                  ord.get(i).oekAntall();
                }
              }
            }else{
                Ord nyttOrd = new Ord(s);
                ord.add(nyttOrd);
              }
        }
    }
```

It reads the txt file, but the problem is that it doesn't difference from unique words.

So if a txt file is for example

hey
My
name
is
hey

It reads 5 words instead of 4.

When the same word pops up, I want it to run this method:

```
public void oekAntall(){
    antall ++;
```

Comment: You are trying to create an algorithm here. If you don't see a way to solve this with code, try doing it by hand on paper and note what you do

Comment: Not sure why you are doing this... but I would put the words in a set and do .Contains on it to add to antall++

Answer (score 0):

If you are not specifically required to read it in one word at a time, why not read the entire line and then parse it? I would recommend the StringTokenizer class to accomplish this. I'll write out some pseudo code to show what I mean.

```
String inputLine = sc.readLine();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inputLine, " "); //parse on spaces
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    //Parse tokens
    array[x] = st.nextToken();
}
```

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention. We are required to read one word at a time. This is really basic what we are learning atm. Beginner lvl